# Ligatures missing in some PDFs

Tags: fonts, pdf

I have some PDFs which, when viewed in readers under Linux (tried `atril` from MATE and `evince` from GNOME), the [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) (e.g. *fi*, *fl*) are missing, as can be seen from the example (it should be *specifications*):

[image]

But when I view the same PDF in the built-in reader of Firefox (`pdf.js`) the ligatures are there; thus I know the PDF is not defective.

This looks like either [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73291) a missing font, but how to discover which one? This is the list of fonts in the PDF file:

[image]

I am using Debian unstable (jessie). What I have of fonts installed is

```
ii  ttf-bitstream-vera                    1.10-8                             all          The Bitstream Vera family of free TrueType fonts
ii  ttf-dejavu                            2.34-1                             all          transitional dummy package
ii  ttf-dejavu-core                       2.34-1                             all          transitional dummy package
ii  ttf-dejavu-extra                      2.34-1                             all          transitional dummy package
ii  ttf-mscorefonts-installer             3.5                                all          Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts
```

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same issue in Debian testing (sid)

Comment: Oops, I meant unstable (sid).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Debian Jessie:

```
sudo aptitude remove fonts-texgyre
```

The behavior comes from the TexGyre fonts being substituted for Times and Helvetica when they appear in the pdf. I ended up installing it as one of the recommended packages of TexLive, so hopefully removing it won't break anything.

This answer was paraphrased from [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-gyre/+bug/1317599) and confirmed [in this one.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1325230)